# Need help with applying trigonometric substitution when integrating

Tags: calculus, integration

How would you integrate the following function with respect to x: 
$$\int \frac{x^5}{(x^2+2)^{0.5}} dx$$

I applied the substitution as $\sec \phi=x$ but then was not sure how to approach the numerator...

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Why don't you just put $\sqrt{(x^2 + 2)} = u$ and then just divide the resulting expression ?

Comment: Probably $x=2\tan\phi$ is a better choice.

Comment: Alternative: $u=x^2$ turns the integrand into $2/\sqrt{2+u}-2\sqrt{2+u}+(2+u)^{3/2}/2$, which is simple to integrate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *need* to do a trigonometric substitution, then $x=2\tan t$ seems a better choice, because, for $-\pi/2<t<\pi/2$ we have $\cos t>0$, so
$$
2\tan^2t+2=2(\tan^2t+1)=\frac{2}{\cos^2t}
$$
and so
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\tan^2t+2}}=\frac{\cos t}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
Next, $dx=\frac{2}{\cos^2t}\,dt$ and so the integral becomes
$$
\sqrt{2}\int\frac{\sin^5t}{\cos^5t}\cos t\frac{1}{\cos^2t}\,dt=
-\sqrt{2}\int\frac{(1-\cos^2t)^2}{\cos^6t}d(\cos t)
$$
which is elementary.

If you do $\sqrt{x^2+2}=u$, then $x^2=u^2-2$ and $x\,dx=u\,du$, so you get
$$
\int\frac{(u^2-2)^2}{u}u\,du
$$
which is much easier.